# Full archive configuration export doesn't work

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, configuration

When I go to `/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export` and want to export the full archive, the site loads for a while and then just goes completely blank and the URL bar shows `/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export-download`.

There is no error in the server log files and no entry in the Drupal reports.

In the sync directory `sites\default\files\config_[...]\sync` there is no file except for the .htaccess.

And when I try `drush cex` or `drush cex sync` this error occurs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Drush\Command\DrushInputAdapter::hasParameterOption($values) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface::hasParameterOption($values, $onlyParams = false) in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Command\DrushInputAdapter.php on line 27
```

I've tried everything with the `settings.local.php` enabled and disabled. But the export just doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: probably outdated drush or too new php version....just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, What is the version of drush?

I advise that you use the **console bundle**(add it via composer:  "drupal/console": "~1.0")

and then execute this command

```
drupal config:export  --directory="modules/custom/import_export_config/config/install/"
```

Comment: I installed the console with composer `require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --sort-packages` but then when I run `drupal list` I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Console\Core\Utils\DrupalFinder::getVendorDir() in vendor\drupal\console-core\src\Utils\DrupalFinder.php on line 41`